# How to write progress bar for a script in powershell that finds specific files and deletes them with Get-ChildItem, Remove-Item

Tags: powershell

I'm new with powershell.

I'm trying to write a script that:

1. will search in a specific path and delete specific files
2. write in a log file all files that were deleted and their paths
3. write in a log file all files that script could not delete, the
   reason and their path
4. progress bar that shows:
   *current path that script is working on
   *how much time script running
   *the amount files that were deleted
   *the amount of files that script could not delete

What I've succeeded by now**:

1,2 - log file made after script stops, but i want to be able to check and refresh it to see if new information was added.

here is my code:

```
#files you want to find, include all in array
$file_names = @('*file1.exe', '*file2.exe', '*file3.exe')
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Hello. A scrip is going to search and delete the following files: $($file_names)." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
Write-Host "Edit file names in the script if needed." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green

#input the right path were to find a files
$search_path = Read-Host "Please enter the path (for an example: C:\workday\*)"
while(-Not (Test-Path $search_path)){
$search_path = Read-Host "The path $($search_path) is incorrect, please input another one)" }

#path to the log file
Write-Host "The output will be saved to a log file in the disk C:\" -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
$log = "C:\deleted_files_$((get-date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")).log"
$log

#search parameters, -recurse: find in subdirectories, -force: grab hidden and system files, SilentlyContinue - continue if there error
try{$search = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_path -include $file_names -Recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | Add-Content $log
$search }
catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]{
Write-Warning "Access denied: $search_path"}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Why not turn this into a function?

Comment: Hi Abraham, if I turn it into a function it will help me to make progress bar and what I mentioned in a post or its just in addition?

Comment: You can do that without a function, but a function makes it reusable and easier to maintain. Did you figure it out yet?